# Display and style prices with and without tax in Woocommerce

Tags: php, css, woocommerce, tax

I have a question about styling a php script and change the way it shows but i cant get it work well
I use this script to display prices including and excluding TAX in Woocommerce.

I would like to display the price excluding TAX first, it needs to be styled with the class amountex (the $price value also)
After the price excluding Tax i want to show the price including TAX on a new row, this must be styled with the class amount

I made a lot of changes but the price is shown without styling and i can't get the price without tax showing first.

Advice is very welcome

This is the part i had done some changes

```
        if ( isset($price_incl_tax_html) && isset($price_excl_tax_html) ) {
                        $price_html  = '<span class="amount">' . $price_incl_tax_html . ' Incl. BTW </span><br>';
                        $price_html .= '<span class="amountex">' . $price_excl_tax_html . ' Excl. BTW </span><br>';
                        $price_html .= $product->get_price_suffix();
        }
    }
    return $price_html;
```

This is the full code

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'display_prices_incl_and_excl_taxes', 100, 2 );
function display_prices_incl_and_excl_taxes( $price_html, $product ) {
    global $woocommerce_loop; {

        // For simple products and products variations
        if( $product->is_type('simple') || $product->is_type('variation') ) {
            // On sale products
            if( $product->is_on_sale() ) {
                $regular_price_incl_tax = wc_get_price_including_tax( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_regular_price() ) );
                $price_incl_tax_html    = wc_format_sale_price( $regular_price_incl_tax, wc_get_price_including_tax( $product ) );
                $regular_price_excl_tax = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_regular_price() ) );
                $price_excl_tax_html    = wc_format_sale_price( $regular_price_excl_tax, wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $product ) );
            }
            // Not on sale
            else {
                $price_incl_tax_html = wc_price( wc_get_price_including_tax( $product ) );
                $price_excl_tax_html = wc_price( wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $product ) );

            }
        }
        // variable pproducts
        elseif( $product->is_type('variable') ) {
            $prices = $product->get_variation_prices( true );

            if ( ! empty( $prices['price'] ) ) {
                $act_keys = array_keys($prices['price']);
                $reg_keys = array_keys($prices['regular_price']);

                $min_price_incl_tax = wc_get_price_including_tax( wc_get_product(reset($act_keys)));
                $max_price_incl_tax = wc_get_price_including_tax( wc_get_product(end($act_keys)));

                $min_price_excl_tax = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( wc_get_product(reset($act_keys)));
                $max_price_excl_tax = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( wc_get_product(end($act_keys)));

                $min_reg_price_jncl_tax = wc_get_price_including_tax( wc_get_product(reset($reg_keys)));
                $max_reg_price_incl_tax = wc_get_price_including_tax( wc_get_product(end($reg_keys)));

                $min_reg_price_excl_tax = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( wc_get_product(reset($reg_keys)));
                $max_reg_price_excl_tax = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( wc_get_product(end($reg_keys)));

                if ( $min_price_excl_tax !== $max_price_excl_tax ) {
                    $price_incl_tax_html = wc_format_price_range( $min_price_incl_tax, $max_reg_price_incl_tax );
                    $price_excl_tax_html = wc_format_price_range( $min_price_excl_tax, $max_reg_price_excl_tax );
                }
                elseif ( $product->is_on_sale() && $min_reg_price_excl_tax === $max_reg_price_excl_tax ) {
                    $price_incl_tax_html = wc_format_sale_price( wc_price( $max_reg_price_incl_tax ), wc_price( $min_price_incl_tax ) );
                    $price_excl_tax_html = wc_format_sale_price( wc_price( $max_reg_price_excl_tax ), wc_price( $min_price_excl_tax ) );
                }
                else {
                    $price_incl_tax_html = wc_price( $min_price_incl_tax );
                    $price_excl_tax_html = wc_price( $min_price_excl_tax );
                }
            }
        }
        if ( isset($price_incl_tax_html) && isset($price_excl_tax_html) ) {
                        $price_html  = '<span class="amount">' . $price_incl_tax_html . ' Incl. BTW </span><br>';
                        $price_html .= '<span class="amountex">' . $price_excl_tax_html . ' Excl. BTW </span><br>';
                        $price_html .= $product->get_price_suffix();
        }
    }
    return $price_html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

edit. The order of displaying the tax is resolved by swapping these 2 rules :)

The only thing i can't get working for now is the styling of $price_excl_tax_html in the first rule. My class seemed to be overruled by the woocommerce class: woocommerce-Price-amount

```
        if ( isset($price_incl_tax_html) && isset($price_excl_tax_html) ) {
                        $price_html  = '<bdi><span class="amountex">' . $price_excl_tax_html . ' Excl. BTW </span><bdi><br>';
                        $price_html .= '<bdi><span class="amount">' . $price_incl_tax_html . ' Incl. BTW </span><bdi><br>';
                        $price_html .= $product->get_price_suffix();
        }
    }
    return $price_html;
```